# Swift Apple Health blood glucose

Tags: ios, swift, applehealth

I got access to Apple Health and I'm able to read the glucose data which is in the Simulator.

```
    guard let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose) else {
        fatalError("*** This method should never fail ***")
    }
    
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {
        query, results, error in
        
        guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
            // Handle any errors here.
            return
        }
        
        for sample in samples {
            print(sample)
        }
```

I gives me this:

> (2020-05-06 19:09:49 +0200 - 2020-05-06 19:09:49 +0200)
> 7.8 mmol<180.1558800000541>/L 811AACEB-F942-4A48-937B-568AD66E1BDE "Health" (13.3), "iPhone12,3" (13.3)metadata: {
> HKWasUserEntered = 1; }

Is there any possibility to only print out the 7.8 mmol?
I didn't find anything in the documents from Apple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sample** is a class of type HKQuantitySample. If you print(sample) then it will print the complete class data.

If you want to print only quantity then try printing as below

```
print(sample.quantity)
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking at? if it answers your question you can accept the answer.

Comment: Solved: `sample.startDate`
Thank you! Helped me a lot. Is there a way to only get the source, like "Health" and the date?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you would also need to extract the double value itself out of the quantitiy. Here is a sample code

```
    let unit = HKUnit.gramUnit(with: .milli).unitDivided(by: HKUnit.liter())
    let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
```

For the source and device of the value you can try this:

```
   let device = sample.device
   let sourceRevision = sample.sourceRevision
```

If you want, you can try out my CocoaPod. It is a wrapper above HealthKit framework to ease the reading/writing operations. Here is the link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/HealthKitReporter